# Should I Use The Back Tick Convention On An Interface?

Tags: c#, generics, type-parameter

When you have a generic class, with different type parameter overloads it seems generally accepted that you use the back-tick syntax in the file name:

```
MyType.cs
MyType`1.cs
MyType`2.cs
```

Is this the same for an interface? For example:

```
IRepository.cs
IRepository`2.cs
```

Where you have these corresponding type parameters:

```
public interface IRepository {
```

and

```
public interface IRepository<T, in TId> {
```

Comment: Personally, I have never seen this even for classes. I put all those types in the same file. That's the only case when I would put more than one class in a single file.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Those are CLR typenames.  You'll see them once in a while.

Comment: I don't think it is (should be) an accepted practice. The _generated_ type names contain back-ticks.

Comment: @SLaks: I know that those are CLR typenames. But I have never seen *.cs files named after them.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: This has nothing to do with generated types. As SLaks said this is the CLR type name of a generic class.

Comment: But you don't (can't) type them, right? I mean in C#.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: That's correct. But still, it's the class you created, not some generated type.

Comment: That's a matter of opinion. I create `Foo<int>` , the compiler creates (derives) `Foo``1_int_` or something.

Comment: Generally accepted where? I'd always assumed that part of the reasoning behind it in the .NET names is that not only is it not allowed in the names of most .NET languages, but nobody would use such a horrific naming convention in any future language, hence there never being any clashes. I've never seen it used for file names, and glad am I of that.

Comment: @JonHanna in place of "generally accepted", please read "this convention has been used by developers at Microsoft". It is clearly more controversial than I thought.

Comment: @HenkHolterman the type is `Foo<int>` only the file name has the back-tick to separate the different numbers of type parameters, i.e. Foo`1.cs (edited, obviously can't surround that example with back ticks!)

Comment: I haven't seen much MS code, but I've seen quite a few examples from them, and never seen this. Where did you see this? somewhere public or somewhere private only? I'm quite curious.

Comment: @JonHanna I originally saw this in the ASP.NET MVC code on Codeplex. They had HtmlHelper.cs and HtmlHelper`1.cs which accepted a TModel type parameter, for example. In MVC 4, they have switched to a new convention: `HtmlHelperOfTModel.cs`, which is actually a bit nicer, although slightly harder to spot as it just looks like a different type at first glance.

Comment: I have a program that extracts type names from the CLR and feeds them back into C# code. Using the types with ` usually causes the code to fail to compile. Outside of a requirement to work with code CLR where you can't get around it, I'd suggest not using ` in any naming scheme, as it might cause errors later on. For example, in CoreCLR on a Linux system, ` is a special character to most shells and would have to be quoted. Please save countless future generations pain and don't use ` in filenames (or identifiers) where you can help it.

Comment: @Walter - given that there are some well-used libraries using this convention, you had better make sure you can handle the back-tick. However, as you can see from the accepted, top-voted answer the community advice is *already* to avoid them, so perhaps you could add an upvote to Reed's answer.

Comment: @Sohnee I upvoted Reed before I made my comment. My code is largely immune from this problem, but I have seen lots of other code that breaks due to this issue. The fact that well-used library uses it indicates that you you be prepared to handle, but in my opinion does not justify using it on other projects. Reed's solutions avoids the problem no not using ` in filenames. Not using ` in filenames is a good general purpose rule. I disagree with your comment about what ASP.NET MVC is doing, why do you using cs` is a good idea?

Comment: @Sohnne why does Microsoft keep inventing new file extensions every time they what something to be a bit different in ASP. To me, all it seem to do is add more cognitive burden  to learning and using the system.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

File conventions are just a personal/team preference.  You could do this, if you so choose.

I, personally, tend to put these in the same file.  If I'm looking for `IRepository`, I would assume that any and all `IRepository` interfaces are all similar, and all represent a "repository", so I'd just look for them in the same place.  This would avoid needing to figure out which of the `` `2 ``, etc, files to search through.  For me, "IRepository`5.cs" is not more readable or discoverable than finding these all in one file.

Comment: Great answer. I think I'll prefer them to be in the same file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
This convention applies for all types of types – classes, interfaces, and delegates.

Comment: I am not sure you understood the question correctly. He was asking whether he should name his source files like this.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: If you do it for a class, you should do it for other types too.

Comment: +1 for keeping it consistent if you use it. That sounds sensible.